# SQLite showing "Insufficient Parameters supplied to the command" despite having enough parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, prepared-statement

I have the following SQLite table.

```
CREATE TABLE "Ingredient_Detailed" (
    "DETAILED_INGREDIENT_ID"    TEXT,
    "INGREDIENT_CODE"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "BRAND" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "INGREDIENT_SOURCE" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "UNIT_PRICE"    REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "AMOUNT_IN_UNIT"    REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "MINIMUM_PRICE_PER_UNIT"    REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "QUALITY"   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "UNITS_AVAILABLE"   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY("INGREDIENT_CODE") REFERENCES "Ingredient"("CODE"),
    PRIMARY KEY("DETAILED_INGREDIENT_ID")
)
```

I have a C# application where I am trying to insert records into this table with the following method:

```
public int SaveDetailedIngredient(DetailedIngredient pDetailedIngredient)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            {
                var saveDetailedIngredientCommand = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO INGREDIENT_DETAILED (DETAILED_INGREDIENT_ID, " +
                    "INGREDIENT_CODE, BRAND, INGREDIENT_SOURCE, UNIT_PRICE, AMOUNT_IN_UNIT, " +
                    "MINIMUM_PRICE_PER_UNIT, QUALITY, UNITS_AVAILABLE) " +
                    "VALUES ($pDetailedIngredientId, $pCode, $pBrand, $pSource, $pUnitPrice, $pAmountInUnit, $pPricePerUnit, $pQuality, $pUnitsAvailable)", conn);
                pDetailedIngredient.DetailedIngredientCode = pDetailedIngredient.Code + "-" + pDetailedIngredient.Brand + "-" + pDetailedIngredient.IngredientSource;
                saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pDetailedIngredientId", pDetailedIngredient.DetailedIngredientCode);
                saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pCode", pDetailedIngredient.Code);
                saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pBrand", pDetailedIngredient.Brand.Trim().ToUpper());
                saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pSource", pDetailedIngredient.IngredientSource.Trim().ToUpper());
                saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pUnitPrice,", pDetailedIngredient.UnitPrice);
                saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pAmountInUnit", pDetailedIngredient.AmountInUnit);
                saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pPricePerUnit", pDetailedIngredient.MinimumUnitPrice);
                saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pQuality", pDetailedIngredient.Quality);
                saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pUnitsAvailable", pDetailedIngredient.UnitsAvailable);

                conn.Open();
                return saveDetailedIngredientCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException sqlEx)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(sqlEx.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(sqlEx.ErrorCode);
            throw sqlEx;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Despite indicating 9 fields and supplying 9 parameters, SQLite throws an exception saying "Unknown Error: Insufficient Parameters Supplied to Command".

I copy and pasted the name of the parameters to make sure there's no typo in them, yet it still throws the error.

I debugged the application during the method executing and the supplied `pDetailedIngredient` has all the necessary attribute values assigned, and I can see that each of the parameters in the command is being assigned correctly.

I have several other methods for inserting data into other tables, all follow the same structure, so I doubt that this is related to the way my method is written.

Am I missing something here? It doesn't feel like this is the right error.

Comment: Please post what you have in the "saveDetailedIngredientCommand" right before execution starts

Comment: I note that the examples in the documentation put the `$` into the parameter name passed to AddWithValue too

Comment: @CaiusJard is correct. The "$" is part of the parameter name. The name assigned to each parameter as it is added to the collection should include the "$".

Comment: @Mark Benningfield … I agree it should match just for readability’s sake, however from the documentation…[Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/parameters) … _”Parameters can be prefixed with either :, @, or $.”_ … I usually will prefix with the “@” character and did not know of the other two. In addition, in my small tests, I tried with/without the prefix in the parameter definition and it made no difference in the “AddWithValue”… same error. In my solution it made no difference either… it worked with/without the prefix. Strange…

Comment: Well, without knowing which specific C# binding the OP is using, there's nothing else to be said at this point.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield as I mentioned in the question, I have other methods which query or insert to the same database in the app, following the same style. the prefixing of the parameters name in the AddWithValue method is optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly wish I had a good answer as to “WHY” this is happening. I can only assume that the “AddWithValue” is doing something I am not aware of. However, after a some back and forth I would ask you to try this and see if it works for you as it did for me.

Is what I changed is by adding the parameters as shown below. This consistently worked with some testing and only failed as expected when the id was duplicated. Please let me know if this helps as I am with you in a sense that on the surface, your code looks good to me.

```
saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.Add("pDetailedIngredientId", DbType.String).Value = pDetailedIngredient.DetailedIngredientCode;
saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.Add("pCode", DbType.Int32).Value = pDetailedIngredient.Code;
saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.Add("pBrand", DbType.String).Value = pDetailedIngredient.Brand.Trim().ToUpper();
saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.Add("pSource", DbType.String).Value = pDetailedIngredient.IngredientSource.Trim().ToUpper();
saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.Add("pUnitPrice", DbType.Decimal).Value = pDetailedIngredient.UnitPrice;
saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.Add("pAmountInUnit", DbType.Decimal).Value = pDetailedIngredient.AmountInUnit;
saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.Add("pPricePerUnit", DbType.Decimal).Value = pDetailedIngredient.MinimumUnitPrice;
saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.Add("pQuality", DbType.Int32).Value = pDetailedIngredient.Quality;
saveDetailedIngredientCommand.Parameters.Add("pUnitsAvailable", DbType.Int32).Value = pDetailedIngredient.UnitsAvailable;
```

Let me know if this does not work for you and I will remove it.

Comment: This works. Thank you.
So it seems that this is a bug with the AddWithValue method. I believe that this was tied specifically to the decimal fields. SQLite doesn't actually have data types, it has affinities but it's all text under the hood. My guess is that AddWithValue could not properly convert from c# decimal to SQLite `real`

Comment: Confirm issue is being caused specifically by the decimal fields. Removal of such fields makes the method work as intended even when using `AddWithValue`

Answer (score 0):

Another potential cause of "Insufficient Parameters Supplied to Command" error

If you use an approach similar to the following for entering data into a SQLite DB programmatically:

1. create a class w/needed properties
2. instantiate class and populate the instance
3. save instance to DB

the class property name and DB column name *must* match (excluding case-sensitivity).

Example (I use NuGet Dapper so exact syntax may differ):

```
    public class StartState
    {
        public string Phase { get; set; }
        public string ArgText { get; set; }
        public string startTime { get; set; }
    }

    // in winforms form.cs
    private static void SaveStartState()
    {
        StartState model = new StartState();
        {
            model.Phase = Terms.Status;
            model.ArgText = _tsarg;
            model.startTime = starttTime4DB;
            DBconnects.SaveState(model);
        }
    }

    // in DBconnects.cs
    public static void SaveState(StartState model)
    {
        using (var dbc = new SQLiteConnection(Connections.SQLiteDB()))
        {
            dbc.Execute($"insert into {DBtbl.State}(" +
                         "phase,argText,startTime)" +
                         " values(" +
                         "@phase,@argText,@startTime)"
                         , model);
        }
    }

    // DB Definition
    CREATE TABLE 'StartState' (
    phase TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    argText TEXT,
    startTime TEXT
    );
```